# Having trouble identifying an element I'm trying to click on an Angular page

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I'm writing a Protractor test and having trouble identifying a button I want to click on an Angular page.  I'm attaching a screen shot of the button as well as what I see in Chrome when I Inspect Element on this button.  There are 4 buttons all right next to each other on this page and I'm having trouble being able to distinguish between them.  When I inspect element they all look the same.  In my code can I use CSS to find this element or do I have to use a different identifier?

In my test I want to click the "New Record" button

[image: Screenshot of browser and inspection panel]

Comment: `by.buttonText('New Record')`? http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText If that doesn't work, just add an appropriate class or ID to make it easier to select.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to do this if you don't have the right unique identifiers

**1. element(by.buttonText('New Record'))**

This was already mentioned in the comments, see also [the docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText)

**2. Create a method for it with**

You can create a method for it with [filter](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter), something like this

```js
/**
 * Get a specific tile based on a given search string
 * or a element number
 * @param {number | string } needle
 * @return {ElementFinder}
 */
function getTile(needle) {
  var tiles = $$('md-grd-tile');

  // Just a quick and dirty check, better to use
  // lodash for it with `_.isNumber(needle)`
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(needle))) {
    return tiles.get(needle);
  }

  return tiles.filter(function(tile) {
    return tile.getText()
      .then(function(text) {
        return text.indexOf(needle) > -1;
      });
  }).first();

  // If you use arrow functions it will be this
  //return tiles.filter(
  //  (tile) => tile.getText()
  //    .then((text) => text.indexOf(needle) > -1)).first();
}

// You can then use it like this
getTile('New Record').click();

// Or like this
getTile(0).click();
```

With the filter you can or provide the number of the tile you want (starts with 0) or provide a (partial) text of the button / description of the tile.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  Unfortunately, element(by.buttonText('New Record')) did not work.  After discussing with my manager we may hold off on Protractor testing for a couple months.  So I'll come back to this and try your second suggestion then.